# cause vs case (in law)

Tags: difference

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cause_1):
cause - [countable] a case that goes to court

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/case_1):
case - [countable] a question to be decided in court

Do "cause" and "case" mean the same in terms of law?
If not, could you tell me please the difference?

Comment: The "law" definition for ***cause*** is highly domain-specific. Hardly anyone who doesn't work in  the legal profession would know it. If you don't, you can ignore it too. I have no idea why Oxford Learners Dictionaries would think it worth giving that ***cause*** definition, but ***a legal case*** is a meaningful sequence that's used all the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  you wrote: "_I have no idea why Oxford Learners Dictionaries **would** think it worth giving that cause definition_". To me, "_would think_" doesn't make sense in this sentence and it needs to be replaced with "_thought_". But since you wrote it, I understand that it's correct. So could you please explain to me why we can use "would" here? What meaning does "would" have here?

Comment: *"Why would you say that?"* implies criticism of the addressee - probably there's an element of *would = will(-power) = insistence, "Why do you insist on saying that?* As opposed to the simple enquiry *"Why **do / did** you say that?* That's to say, although I said I've no idea why OLD included that definition, the truth is I think they did so because they were thoughtless / careless - ***they made a mistake, imho.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cause" in the legal sense is technical.  I've no idea what that definition is doing in a learner's dictionary.  It would not be typical English to use "cause" in this sense, though you might find it in some compounds, for example in Scottish law:

> The Ordinary Cause procedure can be used in the sheriff court where the value of the claim is over £5000.

You may safely ignore that meaning of the word; it took quite a lot of searching to find even that example (in which the word is a proper noun).

A case may not (yet) be before the court.  "The police are building a case against him". Or it may be in court: "The case collapsed when the witness refused to testify".  In these examples "cause" would not be an appropriate word to use.